# Cordova Firebase Remote Config Plugin vs. Web SDK

Tags: firebase, cordova, ionic-framework, firebase-remote-config

Firebase recently announced remote config for their [web](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/tree/firebase%407.0.0/packages/remote-config) SDKs. In an app built with Cordova or Ionic, is there any feature that would justify using the cordova plugin for remote config instead of using the firebase sdk?

For example, I think that in the case of firebase analytics, it's better to use the cordova plugin because it's able to detect events such as app open and app close and I think the web sdk will not be able to track these events.

Comment: remotely configuring a remote service? **This package is not intended for direct usage**.

Comment: I know, the link is just to show the new package.

Comment: Only because it exists does not imply it would be an option to choose from.

Comment: Obviously, thats why I'm asking this question...

Comment: Since the one JS version is not available, there is only a single option to "choose" from... it's about the same as with Firebase Crash Reporting, which is extremely useless in a JS environment.